# How can I change the domain name listed on ipv4info.com?

Tags: dns, ip, ipv4

My domain linked to the IP 50.3.73.XXX listed on http://ipv4info.com/domains-in-block/s49f624/50.3.66.0-50.3.81.255.html dont matches with my real domain.

Here you have another related link:
http://ipv4info.com/dns/s153399/yuvahealth.stream

So, how can I change that domain for my real one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**50.3.73.XXX** -> second link states out this. **so it's correct i think?**

If you change your DNS-A-Records it takes some time (TTL = TimeToLive) till the changes take affect.

When i do a [nslookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup) i get the following (also correct i think):

- Name:    yuvahealth.stream
- Address: 50.3.73.XXX

Comment: Thanks @gooze. The solution was to change the PTR record

Answer (score 0):

The domain were configured as rDNS for the IP address. A PTR was the solution.